# Git : SSL Certificate Issues

Tags: git, ssl, github

I am running git commands in my cmd. It worked a while ago, but now whenever I use a git command the following error occurs

```
fatal: unable to access 'github.com/user_name/repo_name.git/' 
:  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

It worked a week ago, but not anymore when I didn't change anything.  This is quite  strange. My OS is WIndows 8.1 and Git version 1.9.5

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Git are you using? On what OS? (Windows, Linux? Mac?)

Comment: @VonC thanks for responding! I am using Windows 8.1 with Git  version 1.9.5

Comment: Could you try with Git 2.4.6 (uncompress anywhere you want https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe). Also, what `git remote -v` return?

Comment: Is your system time correct?

Comment: @RichardWU Protocol is missing in `unable to access 'github.com/user_name/repo_name.git/' `, are you sure the error says exactly that? It should start for example, with `https`. Like @VonC asked, what does `git remote -v` return?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you've got the correct CA Certificates installed in Windows. 
I believe you can install it by viewing github.com with Internet Explorer, and then installing the intermediate and CA certificates bundled with the SSL certificate. (Right click the lock)